# StackOverflow exception (fundamental architecture flaw)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation

I'm using a lazy singleton following [Jon Skeet's great pattern here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

The purpose of this object is to provide references to all of the other methods in the application.

For example, `GetTheme(Context.Current.User.Id)` gets the theme for the current user, as do a plethora of other methods.

The issue I'm running into is how do I deal with changes in state when the object is already instantiated?

Namely, if a user comes to the website and isn't logged in, the `Context` object is used during the creation of the new user.

However, after logging in, the `User` object is null, because it was already instantiated.

I've tried to deal with this in the following way, making the public property reference a private method that checks for a `null` reference, and tries to determine if it should indeed be `null`.

Unfortunately, this turns into an infinite loop and crashes every time.

I have previously tried making the user object itself lazy, but for some strange reason it doesn't instantiate when called and remains `null`.

What I'm looking for is, how do I make the `User` property of my Lazy Singleton evaluate itself when called, and instantiate itself if it's `null`, but capable of being populated?

The conditions being, the MVC Global `User` object property `User.Identity.Name` is not null, and is passed into the session at load to be pulled in the model, and that a user exists in the database using the username as a key.

```
public sealed class Context
{
    public static Context Current { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<Context> lazy = 
      new Lazy<Context>(() => new Context());
    public UserMeta User { get { return _meta(); } }

    private Context()
    {
        Deployment = GetCurrentDeploymentType();
        Device = (Device)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentDevice"];
    }

    private UserMeta _meta()
    {
        //If the current object is null, 
        //but the user has been authenticated, populate the object
        if (Current.User == null && 
          !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"]))
        {
            //check that the user is in the database first
            var _userTry = 
              Sql.Read.UserByEmail((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"]);
            if (_userTry == null)
            {
                return new UserMeta(
                 new UserMeta((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"]));
            }
            return null;
        }
        //If the Current Instance already has a populated User Object, 
        //just use that
        else if (Current.User != null)
            return Current.User;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a private field, it will solve the problem

```
public sealed class Context
{
    private UserMeta _user = null;

    public static Context Current { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<Context> lazy = new Lazy<Context>(() => new Context());
    public UserMeta User 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (_user == null) _user =_meta(); 
            return _user;
        }
    }

    private Context()
    {

    private UserMeta _meta()
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"]))
      {
          //check that the user is in the database first
          var _userTry = 
            Sql.Read.UserByEmail((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"]);
          if (_userTry == null)
          {
            return new UserMeta(
             new UserMeta((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"]));
          }
          return null;
      }
    }
```